# Why use a tree data structure to represent data in a text adventure game?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, tree

As an assignment for my C++ module, I have to build a text-adventure game.  The problem I'm facing is a conceptual one; everyone is saying I should use a tree data structure to represent my game.  What I don't get is *why*.

Let's say I have a house of 4 rooms. We can imagine this as an 2x2 array. In each room I have two objects. I want to display this data in such a way that I can easily move my character from 0x0 to 0x1 either way (directly – 1 step, or indirectly – 3 steps), while carrying one object with me.

Why is it better to use a tree to hold all data and how will my character move form one node to another? Or is the character a node as well? Shouldn't my character be an object with a list as its inventory?

I'm a little confused about this. I'm not looking for any code, just a better understanding of data representation and manipulation.

The suggestion was for maps. But then I don't understand how my character will "navigate" a map, either.

Comment: Maybe your peers where thinking that you're building a *tree* house.

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what you're trying to say

Comment: It's normal when you learn new concepts to try to apply them to everything. The tree data structure is merely a tool in your toolbox. Sometimes it's a good tool for the job, sometimes it's not.

Comment: There's a ton of things one can use a *graph* for (I know because a friend of mine is dabbling with text adventures too). A *tree* on the other hand seems less useful. But in any case, you got to say *what* you represent with the data structure in question. Did people actually suggest you use a *tree* for the *map*? If so, demand details.

Comment: Obvious exits are NORTH, SOUTH, and DENNIS.

Comment: Why all the interest in closing this?  It's a good question about choice of data structures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for isn't a tree, but a graph.

The reason it's preferable is that an array of "places" doesn't necessarily represent what you want. There isn't necessarily a door between all adjacent rooms, so you may not be able to go directly from one to another. At the time time, in a typical text adventure type of game, you may have some hallways (or whatever) that take you more or less directly from one room to another that's not exactly (or even close to) adjacent. In addition, you may have one-way passages that will take you from one place to another, but you can't turn around and go back. All of these are easy to represent with a directed graph, but difficult to represent with an array.

Comment: I agree with you in saying that a graph is more appropriate for a text-adventure game. However, if I succeed in creating one to represent the map (C++ doesn't have one), I don't understand how my character moves on the graph. Is it not a part of this structure as well?

Comment: @Adrian: no -- your character probably has a "current place" member that's a pointer to a node in the graph. If it's a multi-player game, you may also want each node to have a list of pointers to players current occupying that node (in which case, traversing nodes will typically involve the player registering with a new node on entry, and de-registering on exit).

Comment: It makes mode sense now. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure, whenever the character moves form a place to another place, in reality the program is just switching pointers (inside the character object). Does this hold true when talking about objects? Meaning, most probably each room will have a list of objects as well. When the character "takes" one and "walks" outside of the room, shouldn't I copy the object from the original list to my inventory list?

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, probably. The exception would be if you have objects that are really big/expensive to create/copy and/or you've moving them around a lot -- but at least initially, neither seems very likely in this case. In the latter case, you might consider something like a `unique_ptr<T>`.

Answer (score 10):

If your "house" is a grid and you can move from any grid cell to any other grid cell, an array is fine.  I'm guessing what your peers are hinting at is that you may not want to be able to move from any room to any adjacent room (and also NOT be able to move from say 0,0 to 42,13).

However, with a tree structure, you still cannot represent an arbitrary set of transitions between rooms.

A more flexible approach would be an [Adjacency List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), which is a specialized type of [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29).  Think of each room as a node, and give each node a list of other rooms that can be transitioned to.  With that structure, you can even allow for one-way transitions (think one-way door from many adventure games).

*pseudocode*

```
class Room
{
    string Name;
    string Description
    List<Room> ConnectedRooms;
}
```

Then when representing the character

```
class Character
{
    string Name;
    Room CurrentRoom;
}
```

To see where a given character is able to move to:

```
List<Room> availableRooms = myCharacter.CurrentRoom.ConnectedRooms;
```

Comment: Yes, what I've tried to explain was an [Adjacency List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), your answer is more complete though. +1!

Comment: Note that you don't normally want a `List<Room>`, but a `List<Room *>`, or possibly `List<SmartPtr<Room> >` (for some suitable definition of `SmartPtr`). You normally want to allow several different source nodes to lead into a given destination (e.g., getting to the kitchen from either the dining room or the living room).

Comment: Heh... code is meant as Pseudocode.  I'll make that clear in my answer (been 10 years since I used a language that directly deals with pointers).

Comment: pseudocode or not, still a good answer. As I said, I was looking to understand the concepts and both your's and @JerryCoffin's answers are useful. Now which one I should thick?

Answer (score 0):

I think a tree is a better choice, because you want to represent possible state transitions between rooms in addition to the rooms themselves.

Think of it as a graph: the states are the rooms, but particular events will trigger transitions from one to another.  It expresses the fact that a user can't just randomly from one state to another.

Think finite automata and state machines.

Comment: Note that trees != graphs (in fact, trees are a very specific and limited kind of graph). For most maps, trees are insufficent and you need a more general graph.

Comment: Agreed.  I think a tree is better than the 2x2 array, and graph is better than tree.